# Why would the name of the 慈祐宮 temple in Taipei sometimes be written "Cinyou" instead of "Ciyou"?

Tags: pinyin, topolect, transliteration, spelling, romanization

Near where I'm staying in Taipei there is [a temple called 慈祐宮](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%BE%E5%B1%B1%E6%85%88%E7%A5%90%E5%AE%AE). Most signs write 慈祐 in pinyin as "Ciyou", but some write it as "Cinyou".

[image: temple sign for tourists]

Would this just be a mistake or could there be a reason for it:

- Could it be another Romanization system rather than Hanyu Pinyin?
- Could it be for another language/dialect rather than for Standard Mandarin Chinese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taiwanese minnan. /i/ changes to palatalized /ĩ/, and so ci becomes cin.

Comment: Thank you! This was not clear from Wiktionary's info on the character's Min Nan pronunciation. By the way, the name of the temple is also very often written with 佑 instead of 祐. Are those two variants? I couldn't find anywhere stating so.

Comment: Not variants, but they are identical in meaning whenever 佑 means blessing.